# Bash script won't compile LESS

Tags: bash, sed, less

I have a bash script left to me by a former developer:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in styles/*.less styles/brand/*.less
do
  filename=$(basename "$f")
  if [ "${filename:0:1}" != '_' ]; then
    lessc --no-color -x "${f}" "$(sed 's|^=src/styles/|httpdocs/css/|;s/.less$/.css/' <<< $f)"
  fi
done
```

The folder structure looks like this:

```
-httpdocs
   -css
       -brand
            brand1.css
            brand2.css
            etc...
       global.css
-src
    -styles
        -brand
            brand1.css
            brand1.less
            brand2.css
            brand2.less
        _reset.less
        _style.less
        etc...
        global.css
        global.less
    compile_less.sh <--the bash script in question
```

I am making changes to global.less, and if I understand the script correctly, it is supposed  to go through every file in the styles folder and if it doesn't start with an underscore, compile it with less and use the stream editor command to dump the results into .css files in both the styles and the httpdocs folders, according to their file name (brand1.less gets compiled and dumped into brand1.css).

The problem is, the script doesn't seem to be doing *anything*. I'm a newb to bash scripting, but it seems like there may be just a couple bugs that would fix it (I'm guessing somewhere in the sed command). Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like the script wants to be run in the root of your structure, maybe there's been a change? Either way, try moving compile_less.sh so it's a sibling of src and httpdocs, and changing the first line of the script to `for f in src/styles/*.less src/styles/brand/*.less`

Comment: The location of the script doesn't matter, but *your* location when you run it does. Do you `cd` to the src folder before running it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your script is in the root directory as implied by Clive.
Running it in the debug mode might tell you the root cause.
if not please update with an output of this command:
`bash -x compile_less.sh`
P.S. I'm not able to add comment, thus posting as an answer.

Comment: Clive was indeed right, I needed to move compile_less.sh to the root folder. And `bash -x compile_less.sh` was super helpful in debugging everything. Thanks!